# Icon to the left and a button to the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need you help. I got an input field with an icon to the left. I would like to have the same for a button (with the same length as the input field), a icon to the left and a button to the right.

This is the code for the input field:

```
    <label for="basic-url"><b>Search</b></label>
    <div class="input-group input-group  mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">                                   
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input id="idSearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
    </div>
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En08R.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to follow the bootstrap "logic" using `container` > `row` > `col`, in order to make sure that the rules will apply correctly. Then, you specify the width of the button (`.myButton`) measuring the width of the search icon (42px), so they are aligned. At the end, you add the class `col` in the input element, so it will take the rest of the space available in the row.

`index.html`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark myButton">Btn</button>
    <input id="idSearch" type="text" class="form-control col" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
</div>
```

`styles.css`:

```
.myButton {
  width: 42px;
}
```

P.S: The attached picture really helped!